# Как добавить данные о времени в БД

Tags: php, sql

Доброе время суток! У меня возникла проблема. Я хочу что бы с html формы данные отправлялись в БД и вместе с этим в доп строку time добавлялось время когда был выполнен запрос. То есть для отчетности. Например: в 01.03.2021 19:20 с формы в бд отправились данные о пользователе, и вместе с данными с формы в бд так же в строке time было указано это самое время

```
$sql = "insert into users set lastname='".$_GET['lastname']."', name='".$_GET['name']."', patronymic='".$_GET['patronymic']."', birthday='".$_GET['birthday']."', adress='".$_GET['adress']."',  com='".$_GET['com']."', times='".['$time']."' ";

$time = strftime("%d %B  %Y %H:%m");
```

В самой базе данных у меня при значении string пишет array а при установке значения даты и времени просто нули

Comment: При создании таблицы, колонке куда время записывать ставите DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESPAMP и нигде время не надо добавлять, оно само будет в таблицу записываться.. И вы либо используйте [подготавливаемые запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), либо вручную "подготавливайте" данные перед вставкой в таблицу. Ну нужно напрямую записывать с get, post, request и пр.

Comment: При выводе  данных с бд на страницу  они будут отображаться?

Comment: Гспд, благодарен безмерно, теперь знаю намного больше и не надо было изобретать велосипед, если все можно решить одной кнопкой.

Comment: Будет, конечно, если вы данные выводить будете.

Comment: На здоровье. Успехов в начинаниях!